# VueJS Multiple conditions for style

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, styles

I'm trying to change the style of my div with class "objectsList".
I want to change the style if my SearchFiltersToggle is false AND if in the same time my window is smaller than 1200px.

It works when I just say one condition (!SearchFiltersToggle) but i didn't know how to do this with multiple conditions.

Thanks

```
<div class="objectsList"
v-bind:style='{
  "display":(!SearchFiltersToggle, window.innerWidth<1200?"flex":"block"),
  }'>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"display": (!SearchFiltersToggle && window.innerWidth < 1200) ? "flex" :"block",
```

you can use plain js syntax in the directives, because it's essentially what it is.
you might also need to replace `window.innerWidth` with some kind of a getter defined inside your component, I'm not sure if you can access `window` object from a directive

Answer (score 0):

If `"display":(!SearchFiltersToggle && window.innerWidth < 1200 ? "flex" : "block"),` doesn't work, you can use a computed method like :

```
<div class="objectsList"
     v-bind:style='{isTrue ? "flex" : "block" }'>
<div>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    isTrue: function () {
      return !SearchFiltersToggle && window.innerWidth < 1200;
    }
  }
}
```